# Android Studio Virtual Device connect to desktop LAN connection

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, localhost

My problem is how to set the virtual devices to connect to the desktop LAN connection?

My App need to retrieve data from the MySQL database on the local network for testing. I hope that I can use the virtual devices with different configurations so I can test the app thoroughly.

Comment: Inside the emulator `10.0.2.2`  refers to `localhost`. You can  use it to connect to the server running on the same machine

Comment: How do I get to that setting?

Comment: However the database is on the local network, not the computer

Comment: ... I am working on

Comment: You can then use the ip address of the machine where the server is located. Btw not sure if you know this but you **need** a backend serverside application to act as mediator between your android application and web database

Comment: @akash93 as in '192.168.X.X' where do i put this? Also I use volley as a backend  server side application. it worked well for real devices Is Volley the server application you described? Please help I can a novice to android

Comment: No volley is an android library for making network requests. You need a server application to respond to those requests and provide the appropriate data from your database. The ip address I was talking about refers to the ip address of this server

Comment: @akash93 Can you please provide an answer or an example of how I should put the ip address and the  code a backend application?

Comment: enable data roaming?

Comment: This is way too broad to be able to answer on SO. Look at tutorials on how to design apis to serve data on the server using a language of your choosing (python, ruby, java etc) and once you've done that you'll get a clearer picture as to how to implement what you're looking for

Comment: @akash93 Thanks for you advice, I will study that first. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the the data roaming on virtual device